# MVC any action returns partial view of the same name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a controller where all of the action methods contain the same code:

```
[ActionName("pretty-url")]
public ActionResult Something() {
  return PartialView();
}    

[ActionName("another-pretty-url")]
public ActionResult SomethingElse() {
  return PartialView();
}
```

I name my partial views in the `pretty-url.cshtml` format, and these get picked up fine and everything works.

As every action in the controller will always do exactly the same thing and return the same thing, I would like to just have my controller look for the correctly-named view and return it as above, without me having to explicitly implement it.

How would I do that?

TIA

Comment: return PartialView("yourviewname", model)

Comment: That doesn't really help, I'd still have to implement an action method for each action, which is what I want to prevent. Thanks though.

Comment: just declare a method in your controller and decorate it with the [NonAction] attrs and use it. (or better put it in a base class) or define a single action and return Forwards/Redirect to that action. (Out of MVC from a while, I don't remember if is return ActionRedirect() or something else)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a single action and pass the view name as parameter.

```
public ActionResult Something(string viewName) 
{
  return PartialView(viewName);
}
```

Comment: By this way one can access partial views that are not allowed, right?

Comment: @Mark - the examples in your question have no security features at all. You can add whatever logic you need to this single method.

Comment: @Mark - Oh, sorry. To answer *your* question, yes, anyone can access any views and since there is no validation there will be HTTP 500 if you cask for the view that doesn't exist.

Comment: This worked for me - I also added a custom route so that I didn't have the `Something` in my URL.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a new method to my controller with a string parameter and use it to load the correct partial view.

```
public ActionResult Show(string PartialName)
{
    return PartialView(PartialName);
}
```

Now instead of using `http://your.domain/pretty_url` you will have to use `http://your.domain/show/pretty_url` but this will work with any new partial view you add later on.